# Plural Vs Singular? "different climate(s?) at either side(s?) of the mountain"

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural, idiomatic-language, collective-nouns, abstract-nouns

Would you please clarify for me what would be the difference in meaning between the following phrases?

1. different **climate** at either **side** of the mountain
2. different **climate** at either **sides** of the mountain
3. different **climates** at either **side** of the mountain
4. different **climates** at either **sides** of the mountain

I am confused because of two reasons. First, since **either** can be both a pronoun and a determiner. Second, since I expect actually two different climates, but at the same time, climates can be used as a collective or abstract noun.

Comment: 1 and 3 are both acceptable, but I would say “on each” side.

Comment: On Madeira island, where the weather-patterns can differ markedly from one place to another, the locals talk about micro-climates. (Hiking guides are particularly aware of these and will decide on routes accordingly.)